# How do I use std::filesystem with Qt Creator 5.13

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to use `std::filesystem` in Qt creator, with Clang. From what I've seen, I need this in my .pro file

`LIBS += -lstdc++fs`

but even with that, this

`#include <filesystem>`

generates an error of

> fatal error: 'filesystem' file not found.

I do already have

`CONFIG += c++17`

in my pro file, and have been using C++ 17 features already, without issue.

Version info:

```
Qt 5.13.1 (x86_64-little_endian-lp64 shared (dynamic) release build; 
by Clang 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5) (Apple)) on "cocoa" 
OS: macOS High Sierra (10.13) [darwin version 17.7.0]

Architecture: x86_64; features: SSE2 SSE3 SSSE3 SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 RTM HLE
```

Comment: What compiler and version of that compiler is QT using?

Comment: @NathanOliver updated question with version info

Comment: Nit: Qt-Creator version is 4 or less. Where the `Qt` framework version is given.